# Switching desktops / full screen apps on multiple displays?

Tags: macos, spaces, gesture

I have kind of a weird case on Catalina (10.15.7, MBP 13" 2019). I have two external displays and a laptop screen. The laptop screen mirrors to Display 2.

For some reason, I can switch between virtual desktops and full-screen apps on Display 1 (both three-finger swipe or ctrl-left/right), but not on Display 2. Even if I've selected a window on Display 2 AND have my cursor on Display 2, if I three-finger swipe or ctrl-left/right, the desktop changes on Display 1. I have "Displays have separate Spaces" selected.

Comment: As a diagnostic and since your laptop is mirrored to Display 2, disconnect Display 2 and try switching spaces when the cursor is on the laptop.  Does it work?

Comment: good question--yes it does.

Comment: So we know gestures work, just not when a second monitor (3rd display in total) is mirrored.  What if you were to extend your desktop to all displays (none mirrored) does it work then too?